# Event bubbling/capturing/delegation in ember

Tags: events, event-handling, ember.js, delegation

It is hard to expliain the actual code as i dont exactly know where the problem is, but it will be great if anyone can help in explaining how events are delegatd/bubbled in `Ember`.

I have a case where `mouse move` on `document` is not triggered inside one `view`. This happens when the `view` gets inserted dynamically using `outlets`.

MOUSE MOVE BINDING CODE:

```
 MOVE_EVENT = touch ? 'touchmove' : 'mousemove',   
 $(document).on(MOVE_EVENT, function (e) {
        console.log('move event move=true');
    if (move) {
        e.preventDefault();
        stop = getY(e);
        //console.log('move event move=true');
        var val = pos + (start - stop) / h;
        val = val > (max + 1) ? (max + 1) : val;
        val = val < (min - 1) ? (min - 1) : val;
        inst.scroll(target, val);
    }
});
```

If I load the page with a router URL that shows the view in the outlet by default, the mouse move inside the view triggers mousemove on body. And when I gets into the view by changing states it doesnt happen: here is a log of a statechage that leads to the behaviour.

```
mouse move in repeat view
move event move=true
mouse move in repeat view
move event move=true
STATEMANAGER: Sending event 'chooseSkipTime' to state root.ote.
STATEMANAGER: Entering null
STATEMANAGER: Entering root
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.ote
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.ote.repeat
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.ote.repeat.skiptimes
STATEMANAGER: Entering root.ote.repeat.skiptimes.index
skiptimes view Inserted
```

skiptimes is inserted into an oulet on `RepeatView`. After such a state change the mouse move inside `repeat view` is not getting triggered, or it is not triggering the mousemove on `document`. **At this same time as I move mouse outside the area of the parentview(`RepatView`) then mouse move shows log.**

In a nutshell mousemove inside a view is not triggered. I have put:

```
mouseMove : function(e){
    console.log('Mouse Move in Blah Blah View');
    }
```

in every view inside `RepeatView` including `RepeatView`, none triggers. But mouse move on Parent of `RepeatView` and upwards is triggering as logs are shown.

It is hard to expliain the actual code as i dont exactly know where the problem is, but it will be great if anyone can help in explaining how events are delegatd/bubbled in Ember.

**UPDATE**

After further investigation it looks like the following stopPropogation in ember-latest is causing this, not yet able to understand why its going to else.

```
  setupHandler: function(rootElement, event, eventName) {
    var self = this;

    rootElement.delegate('.ember-view', event + '.ember', function(evt, triggeringManager) {

      var view = Ember.View.views[this.id],
          result = true, manager = null;

      manager = self._findNearestEventManager(view,eventName);

      if (manager && manager !== triggeringManager) {
        result = self._dispatchEvent(manager, evt, eventName, view);
      } else if (view) {
        result = self._bubbleEvent(view,evt,eventName);
      } else {
        //evt.stopPropagation();
      }

      return result;
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide a minimal jsfiddle to reproduce that case ?